# How to append text in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` with random properties and random size. I need to append a watermark written into a `UITextView`. But the watermark needs to have different text properties and different alignment .

Example:

```
This is the UITextView with random  properties.

                         This is the watermark.
```

Comment: If you want a single `UITextView` with multiple text attributes, you'll need to set the `attributedText` property of the `UITextView` with an `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site.  What you've posted is a series of statements without a question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use attributed strings (`NSAttributedString`) instead of strings (`NSString`).

`UITextView` has a `text` property and an `attributedText` property. In your case, use the `attributedText` property once you have created the attributed string.

Answer (score 0):

Try using attributed string:

```
NSString *textViewText = @"...";
NSString *watermarkText = @"\nThis is the watermark";
NSString *fullText = [textViewText stringByAppendingString:watermarkText];

NSMutableParagraphStyle *watermarkParagraphStyle = [NSMutableParagraphStyle new];
watermarkParagraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

NSMutableAttributedString *fullTextAttributed = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:fullText];
[fullTextAttributed addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName
                           value:watermarkParagraphStyle
                           range:[fullText rangeOfString:watermarkText]];
textView.attributedText = fullTextAttributed;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a translation of @skorolkov's Objective-C code:

```
let textViewText = "..."
let watermarkText = "\nThis is the watermark"
let fullText = textViewText + watermarkText

let watermarkParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
watermarkParagraphStyle.alignment = NSCenterTextAlignment

let fullTextAttributed = NSMutableAttributedString(string: fullText)
fullTextAttributed.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName,
                         value: watermarkParagraphStyle,
                         range: fullText.rangeOfString(waterMarkText))
textView.attributedText = fullTextAttributed
```

Comment: At the eight row that is the error   :  Cannot convert the expression's type '(NSString!, value: NSMutableParagraphStyle, range: Range<String.Index>?)' to type '(String, value: AnyObject, range: NSRange) -> Void'